# How do i validate multiple fields using the same field name?

Tags: cakephp

This is the structure of $this->request->data:

```
 array(
        'Capture' => array(
             'items' => array (
                 0 => array(
                    'description' => '',
                    'amount' => ''
                 )
                 1 => array(
                    'description' => '',
                    'amount' => ''
                 )
            )
        )
)
```

And I have to validate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate multiple records with the same fields, you can use `Model::saveAll` and pass in a parameter telling it to only validate.

Note that I don't think you can pass in your `$this->request->data` (the `items` level would throw it off) in the above format.  It needs to either be in the format:

```
array(
    'ModelName' => array(
        '0' => array(...)
        '1' => array(...)
        //...
        'n' => array(...)
    ),
)
```

OR:

```
array(
     '0' => array(...)
     '1' => array(...)
     //...
     'n' => array(...)
)
```

So pass it into the function in the following way:

```
$this->Capture->saveAll($this->request->data['Capture']['items'], array('validate' => 'only'));
```

Here is a similar question:

[Validating multiple fields with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525645/validating-multiple-fields-with-the-same-name/12525934#12525934)

Comment: I have to validte only fields not to use saveAll().Use validates()