# validating mutiple drop downs list with the same name field in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

I'm new to cakephp 2x. I have multiple drop down in my form. All the drop    downs are using same list data, from one table called -> Students. Now what I want is ,when the user select first student in first drop down ,then that student should be minus from the next four  drop down or disabled in next four drop downs.So that the user wouldn't be able to add the same student repeately.   Plz Help! Thanks! in advance.

```
      //Here is my controller add file:
        public function add(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     $this->Group->create()
   if ($this->Group->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The group has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The group could not be saved.  Please, try again.'));
        }

    }


    $this->loadModel('Student');
    $student1s = $this->Student->find('list');

    //pr ($student1s);
     $this->set(compact('student1s'));
  }

// Here is my add.ctp

 < div class="Groups form">

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><?php echo __('Add Students'); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Groups', array('role' => 'form')); ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">


            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('0.name',  array('type'=>'select','options'=>$student1s,'empty' => 'Please choose a  student','class'=>'form-control'));?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" >
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('1.name',  array('type'=>'select',"options"=>$student1s,'empty' => 'Please choose a  student','class'=>'form-control',));?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('2.name', array('type'=>'select',"options"=>$student1s,'empty' => 'Please choose a   student','class'=>'form-control'));?>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('3.name', array('type'=>'select',"options"=>$student1s,'empty' => 'Please choose a  student','class'=>'form-control'));?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('4.name', array('type'=>'select',"options"=>$student1s,'empty' => 'Please choose a  student','class'=>'form-control'));?>
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'), array('class'  => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
            </div>

        <?php echo $this->Form->end() ?>

    </div><!-- end col md 12 -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
 </div>
```

Comment: You will need to use a front end technology like javascript with ajax to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find solution for my problem to avoid duplication of data,This link helps -> [Validating multiple fields with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525645/validating-multiple-fields-with-the-same-name). All i have to do is put this code ->array('validate' => 'true')<- in this line
if ($this->Group->save($this->request->data),array('validate' => 'true')) {

and all done no need to disable the selected list value.